# Integrating of product of sine and cosine

Tags: integration

$$ \int_L^{-L} \cos{\frac {n \pi x}{L}} \sin{\frac {m \pi x}{L}} dx = 0 $$ for any $n$ and $m$ .

I did integrating by parts, but I am not getting this equals to $0$.

Can anyone show this?

Comment: Hint: this function is odd.

Comment: I think that hint should be posted as an answer.

Comment: When it is an odd function, the integration of the function equals to zero. Is it correct? @TZakrevskiy

Comment: @Togepi no${\quad}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any odd function $f$ on the interval $[-L,L]$, then the integral $$\int_{-L}^L f(x)dx =\int_{-L}^L f(-x)dx= -\int_{-L}^L f(x)dx=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\cos u \sin v = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(u+v)-\sin(u-v)]$